# dropdownlist in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

i just could not figure out how i will put my data on a selectlist for it to be displayed on a dropdownlist..

i am using mysql as my database..
on my model i have this query:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Data

Public Class ClassCategoryConnection
Inherits ClassConnection

    Public Function SelectCategory() As DataTable
         Return ReadData("SELECT IDcategory, category FROM category")
     End Function
End Class
```

on my controller i have:

```
Public Class HomeController
Private Category As New ClassCategoryConnection
    Function Index() As ActionResult
        Dim _category As DataTable = Category.SelectCategory()
        Return View(_category)
    End Function
End Class
```

how will i construct my selectlist with this?..=)

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in controller part and send the select list to view.

[Controller]

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> List
{
     get
     {
          List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
          foreach(var data in _category){
                list.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                     Text = data.field,
                     Value = data.field,
                 });
           }
          return list;
     }    
}
```

In the Index Action add the following code

```
ViewData["dropdownlist_name"] = List
```

In the View just create

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("dropdownlist_name") %>
```

Comment: can you please convert it to vb.net?
i can't seem to convert it on the link provided by lucky below..
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In C# ,

Please convert it to to VB for your liking [Here](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)...

first thing passing a data table is a headache try passing it through the view data 
 like

```
  return View (Category.SelectCategory().AsEnumerable().ToList());
```

and in the aspx page try using that like this

```
    Html.DropDownList("list",viewdata.model)
```

this should work ...

Comment: i got an error on the aspx page that says: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'DropDownList' can be called without a narrowing conversion 
but when i removed the "list" it gave me this error: 
Conversion from type 'List(Of DataRow)' to type 'String' is not valid.